Is a "Can I do A?"-type question answered with a "no, but you can do B"-type answer on topic?
Is answering a question that asks to do something with a specific tool or library off topic if another way to solve the problem without the tool is shown?
How to change some columns name when using pd.read_excel
Answering this one I was wondering whether it is on topic or not.

Ambiguous. It fully depends on the question. If the question is a hard "I really must do it with this tool and I have no freedom at all" then yes it would be off-topic. But generally people should be asking about a particular problem to solve and they'll be presenting a particular implementation they picked with not a guaranteed good reason. Asking the right question is hard, as an answerer it is part of the job description to read between the lines.

Subject matter experts may "know" what the asker is really interested in, because they've been down the same road way back when and they've also seen variants of the question numerous times. This phenomenon is related to the X-Y problem. I put the word "know" in quotation marks because this is a form of intuition and is thus fallible.

@Gimby Re: "If the question is a hard "I really must do it with this tool and I have no freedom at all" then yes it would be off-topic" – I disagree; we aren't in the business of trying to mind-read possible answers to questions to try and guess whether something should be closed– either the question is well-scoped, on-topic according to the help center, and answerable, or it's not and should be closed. "No" is absolutely an acceptable answer to on-topic questions, and that doesn't at all make that question off-topic.

The answer "no" is a valid answer to a question asking "Can I do X with specific parameters/constraints Y and Z?" Such an answer does not make the question off-topic. It simply means the answer is no. Questions about using tools for programming are allowed, as are questions about programming itself (obviously). A question asking how to achieve some programming goal with a programming tool thus must inherently be completely on-topic (other issues like breadth, details, and objectivity not withstanding).
If X is achievable without Y and Z constraints being respected, but not otherwise, then that's perfectly OK to mention in an answer which already says "no", but it would probably be of limited use since it's technically a workaround rather than a direct answer to the question (which, again, is "how to do X with Y and Z constraints").
As an aside, be wary of XY problem scenarios, where one might think constraints Y and Z are needed to achieve X in the first place, when really they are not required at all.
